# How to export all the rows from DBeaver with more than 10,000 rows?

Tags: csv, fetch, export, row, dbeaver

I would like to export almost 15000 rows from dbeaver. but my result only showing 5000 rows. but the row count of the output is 15000, why? and how can i export all the 15000 rows?

Comment: Are you seeing the 5000 rows after you exported the results to a csv?